# any can please explain me this boost create_thread line?

Tags: c++, boost, createthread

im implementing a github commit on my repo but i see a line and i dont understeand what it means, here is the line:

```
    threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(&BeeKeeper, boost::cref(chainparams)));
```

i understeand the threadGroup, i know what it its and what its for, i have a function called BeeKeeper() so i guess that is calling that function but i dont get the boost::cref, i dont have a class named chainparams i just have a file called chainparams.h is this just a tag to create the thread with that name or what its for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

std::bind. boost::bind etc. all bind arguments by value. To pass a referece, you need to wrap them with a `std::reference_wrapper`.

`std::ref` and `std::cref` (or boost's equivalents) are functions that return those wrappers.

See [If the stored argument arg is of type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Member_function_operator.28.29:%7E:text=below.-,If%20the%20stored%20argument%20arg%20is%20of%20type)

So you have a variable named `chainparams` that you pass, by reference, to the thread function.

Comment: based on your answere i search in the code and yes, i found a line that creates chainparams = Params().  But if i dont have a class with the variables in it and i only have them on a .h? what i can do then?

Comment: i find something on my code that called its like this: boost::thread(void(*Shutdown)(void*), NULL);

Comment: You will have to share more code if you're going to ask question like these. Is there a link? If the compiler is satisfied, clearly you do have these things. If not, maybe the code is, indeed, just broken.